# Kdenlive: Transitions not working on upper track but do on lower one?

Tags: 18.04, video, kdenlive

I'm trying to put a dissolve effect on the end of some track I placed on "Video 3" track, and it does not work there, it just cuts the clip when end is reached. But placing that clip on "Video 2" track gets the transition to work, why is it? I can't place this clip on "Video 2" track because I need it to dissolve into the clip already there.

[I want the reddened transition to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JPmQ.png)

By the way, this is created just for the end of "Title clip", it is not the one to get when we click on the corner of two overlapped clips to get a cross-fade transition, and even doing that it doesn't work.

The transition doesn't work even when not overlapped with the clip on "Video 2" track.

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the [manual?](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual) More specifically have you read the '[transitions](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Transitions)' section of the manual?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way for it to work: just changed the "track" property to "Video 1" on the Properties tab of the transition. Although I don't quite get how should this behave that way.